# Why is the password input field auto populated?

Tags: html

I have a really strange behaviour of the password input field. When the page is loaded, the first instance of the password input field is populated.

The second password input field, which I added for testing, is not automatically populated. If I change the first password input type from `password` to `text`, it is not automatically populated.

There is no JS that populates this field (that I can find).

[image]

The code for the `new password` input fields are:

```
<input class="form-control" name="User[pass]" type="password" value="" placeholder="New password" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" name="User[pass]" type="password" value="" placeholder="New password" autocomplete="off" />
```

The only solution I can think of now, is to add a dummy input field before the `New password` and hide it.

Has anyone experienced this?

**Update**
- It seems this problem is only in Firefox
- If I open a new "private browser window", the problem goes away. Most likely because this window do not save anything to the cache.

So if Firefox password caching is the problem, then
a) Why does it populate the password field? This usually only happens when you enter a username in the login form,
b) How can I prevent it?

Comment: can you give us more of your code? hence we can't understand by only those 2 lines,in per say it should work as you want it to,the issue might be coming from somewhere else not from those 2 input fields

Comment: Try using a browser debugger, like Firebug or Chrome Developer tools and change the type of the first field from "password" to "text". This way you'll see what the actual value of the field is. Your password field should not be populated automatically :s

Comment: I am using Firebug and Chrom dev tools. I have tested changing type. And I don't see how more form code would cast more light on this problem.

Comment: It could be a browser password cache. Try using in-private browser session. Do you still get password filled in?

Comment: You might be on to something @oleksii. When opening a new private window (in Firefox), the input is not populated.

Comment: I think it's just your browser is naughty and remembered the password from previous attempts. It can also be some browser extension - like LastPass or KeyPass. There is probably a way to clean it up, check your browser preferences, search for "password" and see if you can clean up an entry for the URL.

Comment: I don't use password extensions. Even though the password is cached in FF, it should not auto populate the field. And why just the first field and not the second password field? And is there a way to prevent cached password to populate the input field?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after I installed a password-manager: sometimes when there is a password field it auto-generates a 'secure' password for me. Try disabling all your browser extensions or use a different browser and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if your browser is using a password manager.

Firefox comes with a password manager, so you don't have to have any extensions installed for this to be a problem.

To clear the passwords from Firefox:

1. Open the security tabs in Firefox options.

   You can get to this by either clicking on the Options button and then clicking on the Security tab, or by typing the following into your browser:

   ```
   about:preferences#security
   ```
2. Click on the "Saved Logins..." button to open the Saved Logins popup.

   [image: security]
3. The Saved Logins popup should have the list of all the passwords currently saved in the Firefox password manager. At this point, you can choose to "Remove All" passwords, select a specific password to "Remove", or use the Search box to filter the results and "Remove All Shown".

   [image: saved logins]
4. To prevent Firefox from continuing to store passwords, you can uncheck the "Remember logins from sites" checkbox on the Security tab.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this issue from HTML?